# How to let UIViewcontroller (Game center) responds to the Orientation (Landscape or Portrait)?

Tags: uiviewcontroller, cocos2d-iphone, orientation, game-center

i used the code below to show the game center but if I rotate the iPhone nothing happen and the Leaderboard will be upside-down (not respond for the orientation)

The code

```
// Create leaderboard view w/ default Game Center style
        GKLeaderboardViewController *leaderboardController = [[GKLeaderboardViewController alloc] init];

        // If view controller was successfully created...
        if (leaderboardController != nil)
        {
            // Leaderboard config
            leaderboardController.leaderboardDelegate = self;   // The leaderboard view controller will send messages to this object
            leaderboardController.category = category;  // Set category here
            leaderboardController.timeScope = GKLeaderboardTimeScopeAllTime;    // GKLeaderboardTimeScopeToday, GKLeaderboardTimeScopeWeek, GKLeaderboardTimeScopeAllTime

            // Create an additional UIViewController to attach the GKLeaderboardViewController to
            myViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

            // Add the temporary UIViewController to the main OpenGL view
        //  [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:myViewController.view];
            [[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] window] addSubview:myViewController.view];

            // Tell UIViewController to present the leaderboard
            [myViewController presentModalViewController:leaderboardController animated:YES];
            leaderboardController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90.0f));
            leaderboardController.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320);
            leaderboardController.view.center = CGPointMake(160,240 );
        }
```

Is there any another method to show it? any help plz

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

huh I found maybe a specific solution so I replace the `if (leaderboardController != nil){...}` by the code below.

The code :

```
if (leaderboardController != NULL) {
        leaderboardController.category = category; 

        leaderboardController.timeScope =GKLeaderboardTimeScopeAllTime;

        leaderboardController.leaderboardDelegate = self; 
        AppDelegate *delegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate; 

        [delegate.viewController presentModalViewController:leaderboardController animated:YES];
    }
```

also  need to add a property for the viewController to the `AppDelegate.h` First add a property declaration, as shown below:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) RootViewController *viewController;
```

Then switch to `AppDelegate.m` and synthesize the variable, as shown down:

```
@synthesize viewController;
```

Finally since this code uses UIKit to display a view controller, it’s best to set Cocos2D to use UIViewController rotation.
So go to GameConfig.h, comment out the current `#define GAME_AUTOROTATION kGameAutorotationNone`, and set it up as shown:

```
#define GAME_AUTOROTATION kGameAutorotationUIViewController
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to subclass both of your view controllers, the parent view controller and the modal view controller it presents (somebody correct me if i'm wrong, but child controllers only handle rotation if their parent also handles them) and override the method called:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

You should return YES for both orientations (portrait and landscape). By default, view controllers on the iphone only return YES for `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait`, so you have to handle rotation to landscape yourself.

Read up on this [UIViewController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and this [Technical Q&A QA1688:
Why won't my UIViewController rotate with the device?](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1688/_index.html).